# Dynamic variable in function argument

Tags: python

Let us say I have a function like this:

```
def helloWorld(**args):
    for arg in args:
        print(args[arg])
```

To call this function is easy:

```
helloWorld(myMsg = 'hello, world')
helloWorld(anotherMessages = 'no, no this is hard')
```

But the hard part is that I want to dynamically name the args from variables coming from a list or somewhere else.  And I'd want for myMsg and anotherMessages to be passed from a list (for example, the hard part that I am clueless and I need help with is how to take strings into variables to be inputs of a function).

```
list_of_variable_names = ['myMsg','anotherMessages']
for name in list_of_variable_names:
    helloWorld(name = 'ooops, this is not easy, how do I pass a variable name that is stored as a string in a list? No idea! help!')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dict using the variable and then unpack while passing it to the function:

```
list_of_variable_names = ['myMsg','anotherMessages']
for name in list_of_variable_names:
    helloWorld(**{name: '...'})
```

Comment: interesting, let me try it out

Answer (score 3):

The [`**` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) is a dictionary unpacking.
So in your function, `args` (which is usually `kwargs`) is a dictionary.

Therefore, you need to pass an **unpacked dictionary** to it, which is what is done when `f(a=1, b=2)` is called.

For instance:

```
kwargs = {'myMsg': "hello, world", 'anotherMessages': "no, no this is hard"}
helloWorld(**kwargs)
```

Then, you will get `kwargs` as a dictionary.

```
def f(**kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        print(k, v)

>>> kwargs = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> f(**kwargs)
a 1
b 2
```

---

If you want to do so, you can call the function once for every name as well, by creating a dictionary on the fly and unpacking it, as [Moses suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45168692/7051394).

```
def f(**kwargs):
    print("call to f")
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        print(k, v)

>>> for k, v in {'a': 1, 'b': 2}:
...     kwargs = {k: v}
...     f(**kwargs)
...
call to f
a 1
call to f
b 2
```